# Can glue Crawler read xml zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a xml zip file. Can i create Schema using glue crawler.
I was trying to use crawler XML classifier and added the classifier into crawler to create table.
since its zip file. not able to read. Can anyone experience using the Zip file in glue crawler

Answer (score 0):

AWS glue can read zip files but the zip must contain only one file. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html):

> ZIP (supported for archives containing **only a single file**). Note that Zip is not well-supported in other services (because of the archive).

However, reading xml is very **limited**. Not all xml files can be read. For example, you can't read self closing elements as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-xml).